# Spring controller return file (works with csv, not with image type or zip)

Tags: javascript, java, spring

I have controller that works with returning file (stored as byte array).

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping(value = "/get")
public void getFile(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value = "id") String id) throws Exception {
    byte[] file = findFileById(id);

    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
    try {
        response.getOutputStream().write(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I make ajax get request in javascript and I make file new file with Blob(). It works fine with .csv files, but fails when I try to make it work for png, jpeg and zip files.

EDIT: I can make file in js, but image and zip files are corrupted.
Upon some inspection I found out that image files are larger than original.

Comment: Did you try to specify the correct mime type for result [(javadoc)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html#produces--)? See `produces` property of `@GetMapping`

Comment: I tried with `response.setContentType`, but with same result. Can i change `produces` type dynamically based on a variable (since I return different file types)?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and solved with bellow strategy. you can try with this.
Before write into outputStream, `please set the Content-Type header to image/png (it's for png images)` and calculate the size from given file for bufferSize.

```
response.setContentType("image/png");
byte[] bytesArray = Utils.convertFileToByte(file);
response.setBufferSize(bytesArray.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(bytesArray);
```

And for JPEG file:

```
response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
byte[] bytesArray = Utils.convertFileToByte(file);
response.setBufferSize(bytesArray.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(bytesArray);
```

Comment: Why do you set the content type twice in case of JPEG?